# Promise.all with a big Array

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

So, I have a React Program, where I want to filter a lot of food menus. Everything worked great, but at one point where the numbers of menus increased the Promise.all() method didn't execute the .then() or .catch() method anymore.

Simplified, the code looks something like this

```
const returnsPromise = () => {
    // Here the menues getting filtered
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('bye'), 5000));
}

// All the Menus
const myArray = new Array(1000).fill('hallo');


// Filtered Menus
let newArray = myArray.map(async x => {
        let a = await returnsPromise();
    return a;
});

// Then I can Update the view with the filtered List
Promise.all(newArray).then(res => console.log(res));
```

Do I need to always take smaller chunks of the array, or can I resolve (pun inteded) this somehow?

Thank you very much for your time, this is my first question on stackoverflow :)

Comment: No, the behaviour you describe will never happen. [mcve] please.

Comment: `Promise.all` doesn't have a limit (other than the limit on the max number of elements in an array, which is 2^32 - 1). If you're not seeing either the fulfillment or rejection handler getting called, it means that none of the promises has rejected and one or more of the promises is still pending. If these are network requests or similar, they're probably queuing (browsers only allow so many simultaneous connections).

Comment: well, how many request do you fire at the same time? Could it be that your outgoing requests are simply waiting. Did you attach a `catch` to see if there is an exception being fired instead?

Comment: *"... the `Promise.all()` method didn't execute the `.then()` or `.catch()` method anymore...."* There's no `catch` handler (rejection handler) in your example.

Comment: What is the real case ? because depends on the actions you are taking for each item into the array, `Promise.all` should not finish until all promise all resolve, or if one of them has been rejected so `Promise.all` should throw `catch` block if you define it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers! So there is only one outgoing database request, so that can't be it, I guess. And I cannot get a Minimal Code Example without posting code that I am not allowed to publish. When I make a console.log of the "newArray" it looks like every Promise gets resolved correctly. 
I will test it out further, if any of the promises doesn't get resolved correctly and will report to you guy!

Comment: @Saigo - Have a read through the [MCVE link](/help/mcve) from Jonas. No need for code you can't publish, build a minimal separate test case replicating the problem. You'll probably find the solution along the way; if not, you'll have something you can share so people can help you. That's the point of an MCVE.

Comment: @JohuderGonzalez In the real case, there is a catch Block, that does not execute :)
The real case is a React App that gives Menu Recommendations based on your User Profile and Location

Comment: You are right @T.J.Crowder will do that!

Comment: One thing to remember about `Promise.all`, everything is run in parallel, this is often not a good idea, it's easy to exhaust resources, if it was say hard drive related, good chance you'll have thrashing issues etc etc, and sometimes doing 100 things at the same time, is not as fast as doing 4 things in blocks.  Bluebird has options in it's map called concurrency, but switching Promise lib might be overkill, so a simple NPM lib like -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-map might be an idea.

Comment: So I found the problem!
I was chunking the Array and went through the whole Array bit by bit until I found a chunk that did not resolve. In that I found a Menu that had no location field defined and so the Promise could not resolve. 
Thank you guys for your time again! @JohuderGonzalez your hint helped me to investigate into the Array and to see if it is actually resolved. Sorry that I could not provide an actual example. 
How do I close this Question?

Comment: @Saigo I am glad to know you found the bug by yourself, try using `try and catch` to handle errors in better way.